# What would be a traffic circle or roundabout in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, modern-life, traffic

Out of idle curiosity, how would you translate "traffic circle" or "roundabout" into Latin?
I assume the Romans did not have them, but there must be some analogues to draw on.
The best I could think of is a small *circus* of roads, *circulus viarius*.
But is there something better, or should I go with this one?

Comment: Spanish for roundabout is rotonda < from Italian rotonda < apparently from adj. rotondo, -a < from Latin rotundus, -a, -um, which feels slightly more appropriate than circularis. Ongoing research. I don't think unlikely that Romans has some sort of roundabout

Answer (score 2):

The Latin Wikipedia has [dissaeptum orbiculatum](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissaeptum_orbiculatum) (a particularly clumsy term, but backed with a dictionary reference).